# Signing a Java applet using an existing certificate

Tags: java, applet, signed-applet

There are already a lot of questions about signing an applet, but there's one scenario, which I would have thought is more common, but apparently it isn't...

How do I sign an applet, if I already have the CSR, the CA and the certificate? I think I'm supposed to import the CSR in order to create a keystore and then to continue as if CSR was generate by keytool.

But I tried a few times and can't seem to get it right. I couldn't find anywhere more info about it.

Anyway, maybe I got it all wrong and it's simply impossible, though I wouldn't think so..

Would be happy to get some info / links about this.

Comment: All you need is the password to import the certificate to a different store and the certificate given by the signing authority. it has all the info. what have you tried and where are you getting stuck - give some of the statements. Dont give actual passwords :-)

Comment: What do you mean with "having the CA"?

Comment: [Java Applet & Web Start - Code Signing](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/tech/java-code-signing-1915323.html#60)

Answer (score 0):

> How do I sign an applet, if I already have the CSR, the CA and the certificate?

You can't, unless you also have the private key.

> I think I'm supposed to import the CSR in order to create a keystore and then to continue as if CSR was generate by keytool.

You're supposed to import the signed certificate and it's CA certificate chain into the *same* keystore that contains the private key! and that you generated the CSR from.

Or, if you have the private key in another form, convert it to PKCS#12, import that as a keystore into a new JKS keystore, and then import the signed cert etc as above.

When you import the signed certificate you must use the same alias as the private key.

Comment: Thanks EJP! It's starting to make sense. I have the issuer CA cert and also the private key. I imported both of them to the same keystore. I also tried to import the public cert, but it says that it will replace the private one, so I cancelled it import. But when I use jarsigner to sign the applet then it complains that certificate chain not found. What am I missing? Thanks again!

Comment: Dd it really say it would 'replace' the private key? You can't just omit that step. Otherwise you have no signed certificate.

Comment: Hi @EJP - I run a command to add the intermediate certificate (from CA), then I add the public certificate. I'm not sure what next to do. When I try to add the private then it asks me: Certificate already exists in keystore under alias <aliasName>. Do you still want to add it? And when I try to sign the applet then it tells me that certificate chain not found. I'm sure that I miss something basic, but don't know what.. Thanks again.

Comment: The private key is in the KeyStore first, then you add the signed certificate with the same alias. And don't specify -trustcacerts when you do that. It isn't a CA cert, it is your cert.